# collision detection from picturebox in a list c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that has a predefined amount of pictureboxes inserted by the user and then added in a List. the pictureboxs have to grow and each time they would hit eachother or hit the panel boundrys it would have been game over. I can't detect the collisions between them. Problem you can find in the section with 2 foreach. Thanks in advance

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Boxen
{
    public partial class FrmBoxes : Form
    {
        public FrmBoxes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Defined Global Variables for the User input, points, the biggest box, total of points and the average of points
        int UserInput;
        int Points = 0, BiggestBox = 0, PointsTotal =0;
        double AveragePoints = 0;

        //List of points of each box and another one to insert the boxes

        List<int> PointsList = new List<int>();
        List<PictureBox> picboxsList = new List<PictureBox>();

        //Random generator for color in the boxes
        Random rnd = new Random();

        /// <summary>
        /// FrmBoxes_Load means when the formular will load, than Info will be shown and Timer will be set to false
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void FrmBoxes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Info will be displayed
            LblInfo.Text = "Click Box, as bigger as more points you get";
            //Timer set to false
            TmrFirst.Enabled = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TmrFirst_Tick, each time the Timer will tick will write on 3 labels different values according with the total points, average points and size of box es
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void TmrFirst_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this tree labels  will be written from their variables  values and the value that its in that variable  will be connverted to string 
            LblPoints.Text = Convert.ToString(PointsTotal);
            LblClickPoints.Text = Convert.ToString(AveragePoints);
            LblBiggestBox.Text = Convert.ToString(BiggestBox);



            //Loop that counts betwwen 0 and the amount of Boxes inside of the List   
            for (int i = 0; i < picboxsList.Count; i++)
            {
                //The index of the List will gain a new size of 2 pixels in height and width at each tick
                picboxsList[i].Size = new Size(picboxsList[i].Width + 2, picboxsList[i].Height + 2);
            }

           
            //Verificacion if the amount of boxes in the List is inferior to the number inputed bby the user 
            if (picboxsList.Count < UserInput) 
            {
                //Object Box is created with 20 Pixels height and widht and a random color is generated for their background
                PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
                picBox.Size = new Size(20, 20);
                picBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(10, 245), rnd.Next(10, 245), rnd.Next(10, 245));

                //Event handler will be added to click the box event 
                picBox.Click += new EventHandler(PicBox_Click);

                //Box will be added to the game field with 30 Pixels distance to the edges
                PnlGameField.Controls.Add(picBox);
                picBox.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(0, PnlGameField.Width - 30), rnd.Next(0, PnlGameField.Height - 30));

                //Each created box will be added to the List
                picboxsList.Add(picBox);

                foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                {    
                    
                    foreach (Control y in this.Controls)
                    {
    
                        if (x != y)
                        {
                            if (x.Bounds.IntersectsWith(y.Bounds)) //&& (picBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds)PnlGameField.Height)) && (picBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds)PnlGameField.Width))
                            {
                                LblInfo.Text = "Game Over";
                                TmrFirst.Stop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            
            //Check that the list is not nothing and contains more than 1 element before continuing.
            //for (outerIndex as Int32 = 0; picboxsList.Count - 2)

            //for (innerIndex as Int32 = outerIndex + 1; picboxsList.Count - 1)
            //if (picboxsList(outerIndex).Bounds.IntersectsWith(picboxsList(innerIndex).Bounds))
             //Then slimeList(outerIndex) and slimeList(innerIndex) have collided.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Pic_Box, event handler created at click, will add some values and remove after click
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void PicBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //event handler called with click interaccion
            PictureBox picBox = (PictureBox)sender;

            //remove the box from the game field
            picBox.Dispose();
            //remove the box from the List
            picboxsList.Remove(picBox);
            //Width will be used to calculate the total points and add each time that is clicked//
            PointsTotal += picBox.Width;
            //Width will be used to calculate the points per click
            Points = picBox.Width;
            //Points will be added to the List 
            PointsList.Add(Points);
            //Max value from a box will be token out from the list Points and saved in the variable BiggestBox
            BiggestBox = PointsList.Max();
            //AveragePoints variable will hold the double value of all the boxes points saved in the list and will update upon click in each box
            AveragePoints = Convert.ToDouble(PointsList.Average());

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When start button will be clicked it creates the amount of boxes defined by the user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //new text inserted in the label LblInfo to be displayed upon click on the button start
            LblInfo.Text = "When the Boxes hit eachother or the edges it's Game Over";
            //User input converted to integer and displayed in text box
            UserInput = Convert.ToInt32(TxtNumberOfBoxes.Text);
            //Timer will be set to true
            TmrFirst.Enabled = true;

            //Loop to check the user input and add boxes till his given number 
            for (int i = 0; i < UserInput; i++)
            {
                //Object Box is created with 20 Pixels height and widht and a random color is generated for their background
                PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
                picBox.Size = new Size(20, 20);
                picBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(10, 245), rnd.Next(10, 245), rnd.Next(10, 245));

                //Event handler will be added to click the box event 
                picBox.Click += new EventHandler(PicBox_Click);

                //Box will be added to the game field with 30 Pixels distance to the edges
                PnlGameField.Controls.Add(picBox);
                picBox.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(0, PnlGameField.Width - 30), rnd.Next(0, PnlGameField.Height - 30));

                //Each created box will be added to the List
                picboxsList.Add(picBox);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never removed the box from the controls list when clicked on it.

Comment: I tried out that, or I dit it wrong or in a wrong place, but it still doesn't recognise the collision.

Comment: That was just a bug in the code, not necessarily a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

Your collision detection does not work because you are checking the controls of the form, not of the `PnlGameField`. Use the following game loop instead:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var boxes = PnlGameField.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
    foreach (var box in boxes)
    {
        box.Size = new Size(box.Size.Width + 2, box.Size.Height + 2);
        box.Location = new Point(box.Location.X - 1, box.Location.Y - 1);
    }
    if (CheckCollisions(boxes))
    {
        EndGame();
    }
    PnlGameField.Invalidate();
}

private bool CheckCollisions(PictureBox[] boxes)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
    {
        var box = boxes[i];
        if (box.Left < 0 || box.Right >= PnlGameField.Width
            || box.Top < 0 || box.Bottom >= PnlGameField.Height)
        {
            box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            return true;
        }
        for (int j = i+1; j < boxes.Length; j++)
        {
            var other = boxes[j];
            if (box.Bounds.IntersectsWith(other.Bounds))
            {
                box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                other.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

which I tested and it works .

---

### Other interesting points.

#### Scoring

Create a class to keep track of scoring statistics. Convert the points into float since double is too precise (you get averages of `29.9999999997` instead of `30.0`) and your conversion to double *after* averaging is a bug.

```
public class GameScore
{
    readonly List<float> pointsList;
    public GameScore()
    {
        pointsList = new List<float>();
    }
    public int BoxCount { get => pointsList.Count; }
    public float Average { get => pointsList.Count >0 ? pointsList.Average() : 0; }
    public float Maximum { get => pointsList.Count>0 ? pointsList.Max() : 0; }
    public float Total { get => pointsList.Count>0 ? pointsList.Sum() : 0; }

    public void Add(int points)
    {
        pointsList.Add(points);
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        pointsList.Clear();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Total={Total}, Ave={Average}, Max={Maximum}";
    }
}
```

And the `GameScore` can be used each time a box is clicked with `score.Add(box.Width)`. See source code below for more details

#### Box Creation/Removal

One other point to make is you only need to add a new box after one is clicked and removed, so there is no need to check if the current count == user input, and there is no need to duplicate code for adding boxes. Put in a function and call it as needed.

This a general observation that you will be better served if you split your code into functional units (add functions) and call them from the UI handlers. There is no need to keep a separate list of picture boxes, and you can know if the game is running or not by using the `Timer.Enabled` property.

---

#### Source Listing

Below is the full code listing I used for testing, and it largely based on your code, but with things re-arranged around. My hope is that you can get inspired to understand how to be better at structuring your code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    readonly GameScore score = new GameScore();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            EndGame();
        }
        else
        {
            StartGame();
        }
    }

    private void StartGame()
    {
        toolStripButton1.Text = "Stop";
        toolStripButton1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128);
        if (int.TryParse(toolStripTextBox1.Text, out int count) && count > 0)
        {
            PnlGameField.Controls.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                AddRandomBox();
            }
            score.Reset();
            toolStripTextBox2.Text = score.ToString();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void EndGame()
    {
        toolStripButton1.Text = "Start";
        toolStripButton1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 128);
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void AddRandomBox()
    {
        //Object Box is created with 20 Pixels height and width and a random color is generated for their background
        PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
        picBox.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        picBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(10, 245), rnd.Next(10, 245), rnd.Next(10, 245));

        //Event handler will be added to click the box event 
        picBox.Click += PicBox_Click;

        //Box will be added to the game field with 30 Pixels distance to the edges
        PnlGameField.Controls.Add(picBox);
        picBox.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(0, PnlGameField.Width - 30), rnd.Next(0, PnlGameField.Height - 30));
    }

    private void PicBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            RemoveBox(target);
        }
    }
    private void RemoveBox(PictureBox box)
    {
        score.Add(box.Width);
        box.Dispose();
        PnlGameField.Controls.Remove(box);
        AddRandomBox();
        toolStripTextBox2.Text = score.ToString();
        PnlGameField.Invalidate();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var boxes = PnlGameField.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
        foreach (var box in boxes)
        {
            box.Size = new Size(box.Size.Width + 2, box.Size.Height + 2);
            box.Location = new Point(box.Location.X - 1, box.Location.Y - 1);
        }
        if (CheckCollisions(boxes))
        {
            EndGame();
        }
        PnlGameField.Invalidate();
    }

    private bool CheckCollisions(PictureBox[] boxes)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
        {
            var box = boxes[i];
            if (box.Left < 0 || box.Right >= PnlGameField.Width
                || box.Top < 0 || box.Bottom >= PnlGameField.Height)
            {
                box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                return true;
            }
            for (int j = i+1; j < boxes.Length; j++)
            {
                var other = boxes[j];
                if (box.Bounds.IntersectsWith(other.Bounds))
                {
                    box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    other.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You pretty much answer to all my problems. Amazing job that you did. Thank you so much. I'm already getting a better understanding thanks to you.

Comment: I'm still having some troubles figuring out what to to with the toolstripbutton and toolstriptextbox. Also the readonly Gamescore object shows an error. If you'd be so kind to enlight me on that subjects I'd appreciate allot. Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://github.com/ja72/ClickBoxesGame for the full source code. You might need to [update to latest minor version](https://dailydotnettips.com/choosing-the-c-language-latest-version-minor-release-in-visual-studio-2017/#:~:text=Navigate%20to%20Properties%20%2D%3E%20Build%20%2D,will%20refer%20to%20C%23%207.2.) of C# in visual studio.

Comment: @NunoSeitan - without more information about the error(s) there is little I can do. So please see the comment above with my full source code for reference.